Can't Authenticate to Google Slides API from Firebase Functions (v2)
I need to access the Slides API from my Firebase Function, using the built-in (or some other) service account, not the user of the app as logged in to Firebase. I have ensured the service account has Editor permissions and that the Slides API is enabled, but I'm not even getting to that point.
Ideally I'd like to make the calls on behalf of a user in my org (I have enabled the domain-wide stuff) as outlined in this answer, but for now I can't even get it working with just the default account.
Based on other answers, I've tried various versions of this code:
const {google} = require('googleapis');
const app = initializeApp();

exports.fillTrifecta = onCall(async (request) => {
  const gAuth = new google.auth.GoogleAuth({
    scopes: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/presentations.readonly'],
  });
  const gAuthClient = await gAuth.getClient();
  const slides = google.slides({ version: 'v1', gAuthClient });

  const presentation = await slides.presentations.get({
    presentationId: userSlideId
  });
...

but continue to get Login Required errors. I've tried both in local emulator and deploying to production.

As you've shown, you cannot do this.
You should follow your ideal path and follow @linda-lawton-daimto advice.
Workspace APIs including Slides are not governed by Cloud IAM and so setting the Editor role on the Service Account is ineffectual. Workspace APIs work with OAuth scopes which you're correctly setting.
The problem is that Workspace APIs protect user content and the only way an arbitrary Service Account can access Workspace API user-content is:

Domain-wide delegation to approve the Service Account for this purpose
Designating a specific user for the DWD'd Service Account to impersonate.

There's a hacky (!?) alternative approach which involves sharing a Workspace document (e.g. Slides presentation) with an arbitrary Service Account's email address (~ {account}@{project}.iam.gserviceaccount.com).

Thanks for the response. When I look at the list of service account in GC I don't see anything that exactly matches the pattern of {account}@{project}.iam.gserviceaccount.com . I see: {account}-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com, {account}@cloudservices.gserviceaccount.com, {project}@appspot.gserviceaccount.com, service-{account}@serverless-robot-prod.iam.gserviceaccount.com and a few Firebase ones.

Ah, I assumed (incorrectly) that you'd created a (User-managed) Service Account to use. Yes, those other accounts are (called Default) Service Account (email addresses). One of them will correspond to the identity of the Firebase Function that you're using and, you should (though I've never tried using a Default Service Account) be able to add  its email address to Sheets.

Okay thanks. I've tried sharing the file with the default service account but still no luck. I feel like I'm missing something simple with the auth code. ¯_(ツ)_/¯
